# SQL JOIN WITH NESTED QUERY

Tags: sql, nested

I am a SQL novice and am hoping to get some direction. I have two queries that I have that I need to join and exclude results based on similar values. I have the below two queries that run fine BY themselves but when I combine and try to condense based on differences to the member_impact value I get way more results then I should. The reason I have to use two separate queries is because the dates that I need are of different values. I also have to use an inner join as the issue_id that I need to utilize are found in a separate table which makes it tricky for me.

```
Select 
Rmd.Issue_Id
,Current.As_Of_Date
,Current.Member_Impact
From Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky Current
Inner Join  Lod.Rmd_Iss_Remed_Summary Rmd On Current.Issue_Id = Rmd.Issue_Id
Where As_Of_Date = '2021-08-08'
Order By Rmd.Issue_Id
```

and

```
Select 
Rmd.Issue_Id
,Current.As_Of_Date
,Current.Member_Impact
From Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky Current
Inner Join  Lod.Rmd_Iss_Remed_Summary Rmd On Current.Issue_Id = Rmd.Issue_Id
Where As_Of_Date = '2021-08-15'
Order By Rmd.Issue_Id ;
```

Again the only difference is the dates. I am trying to get a final output that has both of these results with only observations that have a change in member_impact. For example the first query member_impact was 'Y' the next week it was 'N'. I wrote the below query and while it runs I get way too many results. Any idea what I have wrong here.

```
Select currentweek.issue_id

,Priorweek.Member_Impact
,Currentweek.Member_Impact

From 
(
Select 
Rmd.Issue_Id
,Current.As_Of_Date
,Current.Member_Impact
From Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky Current
Inner Join  Lod.Rmd_Iss_Remed_Summary Rmd On Current.Issue_Id = Rmd.Issue_Id
Where As_Of_Date = '2021-08-08'
Order By Rmd.Issue_Id )
As Priorweek 

Inner Join

(
Select 
Rmd.Issue_Id
,Current.As_Of_Date
,Current.Member_Impact
From Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky Current
Inner Join  Lod.Rmd_Iss_Remed_Summary Rmd On Current.Issue_Id = Rmd.Issue_Id
Where As_Of_Date = '2021-08-15'
Order By Rmd.Issue_Id )
As Currentweek 

On Priorweek.Member_Impact <> Currentweek.Member_Impact ;
```

Comment: Please add sample data and also reveal what the output should be based on that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query using conditional aggregation:

```
select Rmd.Issue_Id, 
       max(case when As_Of_Date = '2021-08-08' then ish.Member_Impact end) as prev_member_impact,
       max(case when As_Of_Date = '2021-08-15' then ish.Member_Impact end) as member_impact
from Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky ish Inner Join
     Lod.Rmd_Iss_Remed_Summary ish
     On ish.Issue_Id = Rmd.Issue_Id
where As_Of_Date in ('2021-08-08', '2021-08-015')
group By Rmd.Issue_Id
having max(case when As_Of_Date = '2021-08-08' then ish.Member_Impact end) <> max(case when As_Of_Date = '2021-08-15' then ish.Member_Impact end);
```

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff thank you for the reply and suggestion. I tried your code but get the following error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=CURRENT.ISSUE_ID, DRIVER=3.57.110 
Is it because current is not defined?

Comment: @JC411911 . . . Yes.  `current` makes no sense to me, so I changed it to `ish`, an abbreviation for the table.

Comment: Thank you so much it is working flawlessly and I get the exact results I should expect. I may have some values that are NULL as well as #N/A would this still account for those differences between the two? Thanks again this was super helpful!

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I am trying to add a few more columns from the Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky table but that means I also have to add them to the group by statement which messes up the results. In order to do this would I have to add your query as a nested query. Was thinking something similar to this although it didnt work:  ``` SELECT 
    ISSUE_ID,
    ISSUE_TITLE,
    ISM_STATUS,
    ISSUE_OWNER_ORG,
    ISSUE_OWNER,
    ISSUE_APPROVER

FROM Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky

WHERE Issue_Id IN
(  YOUR QUERY) ```

Comment: @JC411911 . . . Can you ask a new question with sample data and desired results ?

Answer (score 0):

From ( Select )is not the appropriate approach to go with. If you want go with from then 1st name the table
For example : From tablename where condition