# ADDING COLUMNS WITHOUT ADDING IN GROUP BY, NESTED QUERY INSTEAD

Tags: sql, db2

Hello I had previous help on this query [SQL JOIN WITH NESTED QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68841457/sql-join-with-nested-query) and thanks to @GordonLinoff it works great. My question is I need to add more columns and am thinking this can be done with a nested query but I am not getting the same 10 values that I should be getting from the original query. The reason I believe it would be a nested query is because adding any columns to the below query requires me to add it to the group by clause and that construes my results. Any help on this nested query would be very helpful. This is the query that is working great and giving me the results I need

```
SELECT rmd.issue_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN as_of_date = '2021-08-08' THEN CURRENT.member_impact END) AS prev_member_impact,
MAX(CASE WHEN as_of_date = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.member_impact END) AS curr_member_impact
FROM lod.ism_issue_summary_hist_wky CURRENT INNER JOIN
    lod.rmd_iss_remed_summary rmd
    ON CURRENT.issue_id = rmd.issue_id
WHERE as_of_date IN ('2021-08-08', '2021-08-15') 
GROUP BY rmd.issue_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN as_of_date = '2021-08-08' THEN CURRENT.member_impact END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN as_of_date = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.member_impact END )
```

I tried something similar to this but could not get it to work:

```
SELECT 
    ISSUE_ID,
    ISSUE_TITLE,
    ISM_STATUS,
    ISSUE_OWNER_ORG,
    ISSUE_OWNER,
    ISSUE_APPROVER

FROM Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky

WHERE Issue_Id IN
( WORKING QUERY ABOVE)
```

I need the working query with these columns of data added to the results

```
    ISSUE_ID,
    ISSUE_TITLE,
    ISM_STATUS,
    ISSUE_OWNER_ORG,
    ISSUE_OWNER,
    ISSUE_APPROVER
```

| ISSUE ID | PREV_MEMBER_IMPACT | CURR_MEMBER_IMPACT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ISSUE-00020021 | Y | N |
|  |  |  |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the columns except for the issue_id are coming from the Lod.Ism_Issue_Summary_Hist_Wky table. The Issue_id I am wanting is that derived from the original query.

Comment: Assuming you want `MAX(other_col1)`, for each `as_of_date`, use the same method used in the prior solution.

Comment: The column data I would need would be from the as_of_date 2021-08-15 which would be the most current.

Comment: Hello @JonArmstrong are you saying to add a Max() for each column needed?

Comment: Your `working query` has `GROUP BY rmd.issue_id`.  The columns you want to add are in the `rmd` table.  Without knowing more about your tables, I don't know enough to assume those columns are `functionally dependent` on the `GROUP BY` terms, which is required to simply `SELECT` them. Without that detail, we can still use aggregation (like `MIN` or `MAX`, etc) to add those columns to the `SELECT` list, just like the other columns in the `SELECT` list.  Could you provide the missing table detail in the question?

Comment: In short, can you provide a minimal test case, with the table definitions, which has sample data and the result you want to generate, using that sample data?

Comment: Thank you @JonArmstrong that worked I just added the aggregation MAX for each column and it is working beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add the expressions:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN as_of_date = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_TITLE END) AS curr_issue_title
```

And so on for the other columns.